# Openshift 3 Build Error - Failed Sync - Stuck on pending

Tags: openshift

I am trying to build my first Openshift 3 app.  It's a Pyramid starter app.  It works as expected on my localhost.  When trying to deploy on Openshift 3 Starter I am getting an "Failed sync" error - Error syncing pod.

Any ideas what I am doing incorrectly?

My Github repo is here:

[Openshift 3 Pyramid Starter Repo](https://github.com/fatfantasma/Openshift_3_Pyramid_Starter)

Error Screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Most likely you are hitting on current issues with deployments. Go into the deployment configuration in the web console and hit deploy button and see if it works eventually. See https://status.starter.openshift.com/

Comment: I get this error when click "deploy" button. An error occurred while starting the deployment. Reason: cannot trigger a deployment for "os3-pyramid-starter" because it contains unresolved images

Comment: Graham, does that mean its a problem on the Openshift side and I just have to wait it out?  Or is there something I can do now? thx

Comment: An unresolved image error generally means a problem in the configuration if done manually. That said, OpenShift Online Starter environments are experiencing issues on and off at the moment. A fix is currently being tested, but as the change relates to the Linux kernel they have to very thorough in the testing, so is taking a bit of time unfortunately. I will have a bit more of a look at that starter repo you are using later.

Comment: Thanks much Graham.  I would appreciate it: )

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your repo and it deploys fine. Try ``oc delete all --selector app=os3-pyramid-starter`` to delete it and try again.

Comment: I just tried again.  No dice.  I also tried your os-sample-python and it has the same problem. I guess it's an Openshift issue